# How to Delete the data when the App is Uninstalled?

Tags: android, service, file-io, android-activity, android-manifest

I am developing an Android app which creates a folder in SD Card and stores some images. I want to remove that folder when the app is Uninstalled. Please guide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to delete a file's on uninstall the android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977351/how-to-delete-a-files-on-uninstall-the-android-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//for that you need to run the BroadcasrReciver and include the receiver in your androidmanifest.xml file

```
<receiver android:name="com.android.mobileasap.PackageChangeReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
```

// add permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
```

// in that PackageChangeReceiver just delete the file I am deleting the doc file in this below code

```
public class PackageChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
    //this.context=context;
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    Log.d("hi", "Action: " + intent.getAction());
    Log.d("hi", "The DATA: " + data);

    String action=intent.getAction();

    if(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED.equalsIgnoreCase(action))
    {

         String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mycontent_download/"; 
           File file = new File(PATH);

           if (file.exists())
           {
              String listOfFiles [] = file.list();
               if (listOfFiles!=null)
               {
                  if (listOfFiles.length>0)
                  {
                      int size = listOfFiles.length;
                      for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
                      {
                          if (listOfFiles[i].substring(listOfFiles[i].length()-4, listOfFiles[i].length()).equalsIgnoreCase(".doc"))
                          {
                              File f1 = new File(PATH+listOfFiles[i]);
                              f1.delete();
                          }

                      }
                    }
                  }
               }
```

Comment: That broadcast gets triggered for 3rd party apps, not for your own.

Answer (score 3):

Simple: Not possible.

There is currently no uninstall-event that get's triggered when your own app gets uninstalled. Hence you can't react to that in any way.

The only exception: Store your data in the folders provided by [`Context.getExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)
or [`Context.getExternalCacheDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29). These will get deleted when your app gets uninstalled.

Answer (score 2):

on API level 8 or greater use the external cache directory: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#ExternalCache

There is also an explanation for using API level 7 and lower in the above link