# Handling of android app uninstallation

Tags: android, uninstallation, app-data

I have created some files through my android application. I want to remove these files when the application is removed from the device. How can I get it done. Any help will be appreciated..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: possible dublicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/q/1222269/609765

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please read the link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

If you create them in the correct locations, they will be removed automatically.

Comment: I was storing the data, /sdcard/Android/data/myproject/file1

What do u mean by correct locations..?

Answer (score 0):

Check up the storage section of Data Storage section of Dev Guide doc.

If you use those approaches other than external storage, your data will be automatically removed when uninstalling app.