# Can I delete SD card data specific to an application at uninstall?

Tags: android

Can I delete SD card data specific to an application while uninstalling the application programmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574277/android-delete-files-on-sd-card-on-uninstall

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        File checkFile = new File("/sdcard/Accentra/");//getting the control of sdcard files
        deleteDir(checkFile);
    }

    //Deleting the temperary folder and the file created in the sdcard
    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) 
    {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) 
        {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) 
            {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) 
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        // The directory is now empty so delete it
        return dir.delete();
    }
```

Comment: I do have several activities in my application, I which activity i have to write the onDestroy() method?