# Will the JSON File be deleted after app uninstallation?

Tags: android, json

I have several JSON files programmatically saved using the Android Application I just created.
I just wonder if the JSON files will be deleted physically after I uninstall my app.
Does anybody have any idea?
I would greatly appreciate if there is.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222269/how-to-delete-files-created-by-the-application-on-uninstall) basically the type of the file does not matter, only the paths where you are putting them do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you saved your JSON file, but it will be deleted if you save it to Internal Storage:

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#InternalVsExternalStorage):

- It's always available.
- Files saved here are accessible by only your app by default.
- **When the user uninstalls your app, the system removes all your app's files from internal storage.**

See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage).

Answer (score 1):

If you save file in  your application CacheDir then it is automatically detect when you uninstall the application.

So, save file in sdcard  folder without CacheDir folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I just wonder if the JSON files will be deleted physically after I uninstall my app.

If they are stored on internal storage, or in `getExternalFilesDir()`, or in `getExternalCacheDir()`, they will be removed on an uninstall.