# Removing residual files of any application on Uninstall

Tags: android

After uninstalling an application how to delete the residual files the app leaves behind ( programmatically )
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete files created by the application on uninstall?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222269/how-to-delete-files-created-by-the-application-on-uninstall)

Answer (score 1):

Resources inside directory of your package name is cleared automatically when uninstalled the app.
To delete related sdcard data third party apps give option to remove it Implicitly e.g. Clean master app gives that option.

Comment: thnx but  i m asking about how we do programatically don't want any third party application.

Comment: That is not possible for our own app
kindly check that http://stackoverflow.com/a/6209769/3303075

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219328/how-to-show-an-activity-before-my-app-is-uninstalled-android
Check this out