# How to delete files while uninstalling app

Tags: android

I have a question, because when I install app, I create .csv file and it's the most important file for my app. When I use this app I always check is this file exists. I put this file on storage, but when I uninstall this app, this file wasn't removed. It's still exits. So what can I do to remove this file automatically? Thanks for response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete files created by the application on uninstall?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222269/how-to-delete-files-created-by-the-application-on-uninstall)

Comment: In other words, store the file in a location that will be removed automatically when your app is uninstalled. That's mostly through using methods on `Context`, like `getFilesDir()` and `getExternalFilesDir()`.

Comment: `when I install app, I create .csv file`. Impossible. As you are not installing as Android does that for you. You can only create a csv file at --first- start of your app.

Answer (score 0):

All you need do is to locate the file and delete it manually.
Some apps are built to startup from where you left off, especially apps that have regular updates.
Its just a backup plan.
If you're sure you don't need it anymore, simply locate and delete it.

Comment: It's impossile, because I don't know when user will uninstall application, so I don't know when I should find this file and delete it manually.